# Problems with MySQL database creation in Django

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up MySQL database to use in my django project, but getting erroe that database do not exist.
I understand that first I should create it in MySQL console so I tried it like this:

```
$ mysql --username=myuser --password=1111
mysql> CREATE DATABASE 'myDB' CHARSET utf-8
```

when I hit enter after line above I'm getting following line

```
->
```

I assume that database is not created.
I tried to do this in my system terminal and also in my project environment

So my questions:

1. Why DB is not created with command above ?

2. How should I create DB?

3. Do I need to use this weird quote ` or can use simple one like this ' ?

Comment: you missing ";" at the end. CREATE DATABASE myDB CHARSET utf-8;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL commands need to be *finalised* with `;`

```
CREATE DATABASE 'myDB' CHARSET utf-8;
```